# How do I aggregate this in SQL

Tags: sql

I've got a table with these fields:

```
UserLogonAuditID, Username, LogonDate FROM dbo.UserLogonAudit
```

Querying with this:

```
SELECT  Username ,
        DATEPART(Year, LogonDate) [Year] ,
        DATENAME(MONTH, LogonDate) [Month] ,
        COUNT(1) [LoginCount] ,
        CAST(DATEPART(Year, LogonDate) AS VARCHAR(4))
        + CAST(DATEPART(Month, LogonDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [YearMonth] ,
        CAST(CAST(DATEPART(Year, LogonDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-'
        + CAST(DATEPART(Month, LogonDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-1' AS datetime) AS [MonthStart]
FROM    UserLogonAudit
GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, LogonDate) ,
        DATENAME(Month, LogonDate) ,
        DATEPART(Month, LogonDate) ,
        Username
HAVING  Username = 'demo@mybusiness.com'
```

results in this:

```
> Username           Year        Month  LoginCount  YearMonth   MonthStart
> demo@mybusiness.com   2010    February    1   20102   2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2010    June       1    20106   2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2011    November    1   201111  2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2012    April     115   20124   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2012    January     1   20121   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to get this result

```
> Username           Year        Month  LoginCount  YearMonth   MonthStart
> demo@mybusiness.com   2010    February    1   20102   2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2010    June       1    20106   2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2011    November    1   201111  2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2012    April     115   20124   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
> demo@mybusiness.com   2012    January     1   20121   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000    > 
> user@mybusiness.com   2010    February    3   20102   2010-02-01 00:00:00.000
> user@mybusiness.com   2010    June       2    20106   2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
> user@mybusiness.com   2011    November    0   201111  2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
> user@mybusiness.com   2012    April     190   20124   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
> user@mybusiness.com   2012    January     6   20121   2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

So, for all users.

I can loop through the usernames, but feel that is not the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove `HAVING  Username = 'demo@mybusiness.com'` clause from your sql

Comment: WOW lol. don't I feel silly now! I guess I can only say lack of sleep is my defense!